# phpBB3 mod works on one server, but won't on another

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb3

I am helping a friend install a "force users to re-agree to terms" mod on his phpBB 3 forum. I copied all of his files and his database to my server and installed the mod. Everything worked flawlessly on my server. I then transfered the edited files to my friends hosting acount, and its like none of the files were ever touched. Even though I added new forms into the adm/style/acp_main.php file, it wont show up on the admin panel index. I've waited two days thinking it may have been a cache issue, with no luck. Has anyone else ever had this issue?

Comment: this questions is not the proper SO format. Post some code, an error message, something that helps people propose a solution, this question will lead to lengthy discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The administrator on those boards need to clean the cache files too.

This can be found in the ACP section.